# Complete removal of php and all of it's dependencies o RHEL7

Tags: php, linux, yum, rhel, rhel7

I am trying to uninstall php and all of its modules from a RHEL7 server completely and do a clean install later.

Things I have tried till now

using yum - sudo yum remove 'php*'.

After the above command i can still see that php is not uninstalled. Please help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could also add this option to /etc/yum.conf: clean_requirements_on_remove=1.
Once this is done, you can remove the PHP packages normally, and afterward, run yum autoremove.

yum autoremove will remove any un-needed dependencies, so it may also remove other dependencies not related to PHP, but only if they're not needed.